# BlackBerry 7 too much resources data error

Tags: eclipse, blackberry

I've switched to BlackBerry 7 JRE inside Eclipse. I am coming from BlackBerry's JRE 6.
I've tried to build an old application, which builded without any problem before with JRE 5 and 6 and I get this error:
Error!: too much resource data, max allowed: 7802880, found: 24784054

But there is not such amount of data under resources.

Anyone has crossed with this issue before?

Answer (score 3):

I've found what is causing so much overhead.

By default the compiler will translate all non-PNG files to PNG so the device doesn't have to decode it on the fly.

That increases resources sizes.

In the App Descriptor, under the Build tab, make sure that the option "Convert all images to PNG" is unchecked.